# Simple move javascript game

Tags: javascript, game-engine, move

what wrong with my code

```
function move(x,y)
        {
            setInterval(function()
            {
                gameArea.clear();
                gamePiece.x += x;
                gamePiece.y += y;
                gamePiece.update();
            }, 100);
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onkeyup = function(e)
        {
            var myInterval;
            if(e.keyCode == 37)
            {
                move(10,0);
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 38)
            {
                move(0,-10);
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 39)
            {
                move(-10,0);
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 40)
            {
                move(0,10);
            }
        }
```

This produce output i'm not expected, and the object can't move correctly.
Please help me to fixed this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: You should also consider using the stack snippet, and provide a live working example. It will allow us to easily copy the code, and provide feedback much easier. Help us help you.

Comment: From what it appears like, you're calling `setInterval` in your move function. That is literally creating a copy EVERY TIME that function is called, which causes multiple `setInterval`'s to stack on top of each other. Consider using `clearInterval()` to see if one is running, or consider using `setInterval` once to move the game board, and then simply dynamically update the next movement.

Comment: my expect is if i press leftkey , the object i made can move left, so too if i click right   button, the object move to right correctly.. but in my sample code above,, if i have clicked the left button and then clicked the other  buttons, it will make the object move not correctly

Comment: As I've stated, please either provide a working snippet so I can help provide a solution, or consider reading what I last wrote which explains why this is most likely happening.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/a30Ql4

Comment: Just move `var interv` outside the function (Because that will always reinitialize the variable), and your code works fine (Although your X axis is reversed, but that's an easy fix)

Comment: @FrankerZ: your comment is a correct answer, just make one out of it.